# ERROR: update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_03de2dc08c" on table "comments"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, web, activerecord

I am stuck on this error and not able to figure out whats wrong.

rails aborted! ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table "users" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_03de2dc08c" on table "comments" DETAIL: Key (id)=(11) is still referenced from table "comments". : DELETE FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 #31

Comment: What does your table look like?

Comment: Its fixed now! Thanks

Comment: Yes, I did that.  Ty:)

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like user number 11 made some comments and the user hence cannot be deleted because those comments still refer to that user. This is what a foreign key is- entries on the comments table (a child table) are keyed to the parent table (user) - the parent cannot be deleted because that would leave orphan records

Delete user 11's comments first, or change the foreign key so it's "on delete cascade" mode - deletion of the parent will cause automatic deletion of the child records

Comment: the comments are associated with the events and I dont have any events in db now but I still have comments. How do I delete comments?

Comment: Your question didn't mention an events table; I just interpreted what I saw: the attempt to delete user 11 failed. Excuse there is a relationship between comments and users that will break down if the user is deleted. Delete comments by user 11 before deleting user 11