# ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table violates foreign key constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is a very similar question on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47624334/error-update-or-delete-on-table-users-violates-foreign-key-constraint-fk-rai). The answer given is as follows:

> Delete user 11's comments first, or change the foreign key so it's "on
>   delete cascade" mode - deletion of the parent will cause automatic
>   deletion of the child records

But I thought that was the purpose of `dependent: :destroy`. When you delete the record, it deletes its associations.

I have the following:

```
class Venue < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :entrees, dependent: :destroy
end

class Entree < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :venue
end
```

I attempt the following:

```
Venue.delete_all
DELETE FROM "venues"
ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "venues" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_8fda228aa3" on table "entrees"
```

Am I missing the purpose of `dependent: :destroy`? Also if `dependent: :destroy` is only intended to delete the associations if they do not have foreign key constraints, then how can I delete the dependents with foreign key constraints? Is there a Rails CASCADE option?

Comment: delete_all does not trigger dependent, callbacks etc. Try destroy_all.

Answer (score 4):

Its Working  try This

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disable_referential_integrity do
Book.destroy_all
Genre.destroy_all
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following

```
Venue.destroy_all
```

It's working for me

```
Venue.delete_all
```

Not working