# PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table "xxx" violates foreign key constraint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

I have several tables that have foreign key constraints associated with them, each referencing the other in a hierarchical fashion as outlined below.

When I try to destroy a Company that has at least 1 Project, that has at least 1 Task, that has at least 1 TaskTime like so...

```
irb(main):014:0> Company.first.destroy
```

I get the below output and error. I am under the impression now that simply having `dependent: :delete_all` doesn't deal with the foreign key constraints, is this true? If so, how do I deal with this scenario? I know about the `before_destroy` callback, do I have to use it in this case? If so, how do I temporarily disable the foreign key constraints in order to destroy all the associated rows down the line? What's making this even more confusing is that I have an old rails project that has the same table/model set up only it's a single `model_a has_many model_bs, dependent: delete_all` relationship with a foreign key constraint and I can `ModelB.destroy_all` and it works, so I don't get it. I've also read posts where setting cascading deletes on the table works and some posts saying that this need not be done if you handle it yourself in code; I'd like to handle this in my code if the solution isn't too hairy.

```
Company Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" ORDER BY 
                              "companies"."id" ASC LIMIT $1 [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
             SQL (0.9ms)  DELETE FROM "projects" 
                          WHERE "projects"."company_id" = $1 [["company_id", 3]]
   (0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
             Traceback (most recent call last):
   1: from (irb):13
             ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey (PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR:  update or delete on table "projects" violates foreign key constraint "fk_rails_02e851e3b7" on table "tasks"
                          DETAIL:  Key (id)=(4) is still referenced from table "tasks".
                        : DELETE FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."company_id" = $1)
```

**Schema**

```
# /db/schema.rb

create_table "companies", force: :cascade do |t|
...
end

create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
...
end

create_table "tasks", force: :cascade do |t|
...
end

create_table "task_times", force: :cascade do |t|
...
end
...

add_foreign_key "projects", "companies"
add_foreign_key "tasks", "projects"
add_foreign_key "task_times", "tasks"
```

**Models**

```
# /models/company.rb

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :projects, dependent: :delete_all
...
end

# /models/project.rb

class Project < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tasks, dependent: :delete_all
...
end

# /models/task.rb

class Task < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :task_times, dependent: :delete_all
...
end

# /models/task_time.rb

class TaskTime < ApplicationRecord
...
end
```

Comment: Also mind running `.delete` on an object does not run callbacks (like dependent: ).
These are run when one calls `.destroy`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_many):

> **has_many**(name, scope = nil, options = {}, &extension)
>   [...]
>
> - `:dependent`
>     Controls what happens to the associated objects when their owner is destroyed. Note that these are implemented as callbacks, and Rails executes callbacks in order. Therefore, other similar callbacks may affect the `:dependent` behavior, and the `:dependent` behavior may affect other callbacks.
>
>   - `:destroy` causes all the associated objects to also be destroyed.
>   - `:delete_all` causes all the associated objects to be deleted directly from the database (so callbacks will not be executed).
>   - [...]

So `:delete_all` does take care of foreign keys but, since no callbacks are invoked, it only goes one level deep. So this in `Company`:

```
has_many :projects, dependent: :delete_all
```

means that calling `#destroy` on a company will directly delete the associated `projects` from the database. But that won't see this:

```
has_many :tasks, dependent: :delete_all
```

that you have in `Project` and you end up trying to delete projects that are still referenced in `tasks` as the error message indicates.

You could switch all your associations to `dependent: :destroy`, this will pull everything out of the database before destroying them and callbacks will be called (which will load more things out of the database only to destroy them which will load more things out of the database...). The end result will be a lot of database activity but all the foreign keys will be properly followed.

Alternatively, you could put the logic inside the database where it usually belongs by specifying [`on delete cascade` on the foreign key constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK):

> CASCADE specifies that when a referenced row is deleted, row(s) referencing it should be automatically deleted as well

Your `add_foreign_key` calls would look like:

```
add_foreign_key "projects", "companies", on_delete: :cascade
add_foreign_key "tasks", "projects", on_delete: :cascade
add_foreign_key "task_times", "tasks", on_delete: :cascade
```

in this case. You'd probably want to leave the `dependent: :delete_all`s in your models as a reminder as to what's going on, or you could leave yourself a comment.

Comment: And that’s why my old app works...because it’s only one level deep! Ty.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and accomplished what I needed by simply destroying the records in the associated table first, and *then* destroying the main table. That way it was not violating referential integrity and there was consequently no error.

I got this answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48234261/5783745)

Answer (score -5):

I have the same problem and i fix them with

```
rake db:reset
```

Comment: Hey @rztprog. Sorry to see your unexplained downvote. I think your answer could use a bit of work though. I bet this was downvoted because '-rails' isn't really a valid command (at least on my command line). Also, a blind reset of the db might fix your issue, but doesn't get to the heart of the problem. Thanks for your contribution, and I hope you keep answering questions and growing as a programmer! Cheers!

Comment: Thanks @JaredMenard for your feedback, you right the command is "rails db:reset" not "-rails db:reset", everyday i learn, i found my first mission as a freelancer recently, I hope to join a company soon! :)

Comment: If we are working on production we can't run such command, so it's not useful answer.
we can get this issue if we import dump from another database for example