# PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table "projects" violates foreign key constraint

Tags: ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to delete a Project..

```
class User < ApplicationRecord  
    has_many :projects, dependent: :delete_all  
end

class Project < ApplicationRecord  
    belongs_to :user  
    has_many :tasks  
end

class Task < ApplicationRecord  
    belongs_to :project, dependent: :delete_all  
end
```

Comment: It might be as easy as `has_many :tasks, dependent: :delete_all` in your Project class.

Comment: Thank you, that worked.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PG::ForeignKeyViolation: ERROR: update or delete on table "xxx" violates foreign key constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48739646/pgforeignkeyviolation-error-update-or-delete-on-table-xxx-violates-foreign)